# Will view listeners and network callbacks lead to memory leak problems?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, callback, onclicklistener

Non-static inner class object will have a reference of the outer class object , if the anonymous object such as views OnClickListener or network response Callback have longer lifecycle than Activity or other outer class object,  will this situation cause memory leaks?   if it will , what can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

yes, this situation will cause a memory leak .

> **to avoid/fix that** :
>
> 1. Do not keep long-lived references (use WeakReference)
> 2. Avoid non-static inner classes
> 3. Clean/Stop all your handlers/listeners onDestroy();

**take a look at this project**

https://github.com/AliEsaAssadi/avoid-memory-leak-android

i explain and show common patterns of memory leaks in Android development and how to fix them

> how to avoid network response callback memory leak

- [AsyncTask](https://github.com/AliEsaAssadi/avoid-memory-leak-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/aliesaassadi/memoryleak/AsyncTask)

in AsyncTask Example here will let you you get the answer about :

how to avoid this when we use `Inner class`/ `static class` and show the best practical way to make a network response callback using WeakReference

Answer (score 1):

If you have a anonymous class declarations inside your `Activity` like event call backs, it won't cause any problem as it's life cycle will be coupled with `Activity` life cycle and it won't even last without `Activity` being alive. But when coming to network calls as they are done on background worker threads, it has different life cycle and scope than `Activity`, so if you have `non-static` `Asynctaks,Hanlders` etc they can withstand for long without depending on `Activity` Lifecycle which causes memory leaks if not handled properly.

**Solution**

1. Cancel all the background tasks or network calls while destroying `activity` i.e on `onDestroy` method.
2. Create `static` inner classes for `AsynTask` or `Handlers` and pass weak reference of `context` if in case you need it.

Comment: "and it won't even last without `Activity` being alive", how is this guaranteed? Once I tried store a `WeakReference` of a `Button` in an `Activity`'s `static` field, and even after the `Activity`'s destroyed (`finish()`ed with dev option "do not keep Activities" on) and triggered `gc` via adb, I retrieved the the `View` and it's still valid.

Comment: `gc` cycles are so random that we can't guarantee garbage collection happens right away but it's better to assume that away to avoid problems

Comment: Well... Perhaps. I'd assume there's far too enough memory for small things like views and listeners to leak before user close the app. Thanks anyway~ meow.